# WebRTC : attachMediaStream

Tags: webrtc

Suppose for an incoming remote stream in WebRTC, I do not attach it to a video element using `attachMediaStream(<videoElement>, <remoteStream>);`.

I want to understand what happens now?

1. Is the stream still being sent by remote peer and I am not just displaying it as I have not attached to a video element
2. Remote has stopped streaming to me as I have not accepted the stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attachMediaStream` is a part of the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) library. That library is a [shim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing) which contains "glue" code to abstract away differences between the browsers (Chrome/Firefox often have experimental API's prefixed with `moz` or `webkit`).

`attachMediaStream` was (deprecated now) responsible for attaching a [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API) to a HTML video element. Nothing more.

You can have a look at the source for Firefox [here](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/master/src/js/firefox/firefox_shim.js):

```
  attachMediaStream: function(element, stream) {
    logging('DEPRECATED, attachMediaStream will soon be removed.');
    element.srcObject = stream;
  },
```

So 1. yes 2. no. Since attachMediaStream is purely a "local" helper to display the stream.

*attachMediaStream is not exclusive to adapter.js, that is just the most common adapter/helper library used.

Comment: I there a way to do the second case i.e. tell the remote peer to stop sending stream to me.

Comment: Sounds like you want to mute the video of the remote? You could do that by sending the remote party a "please mute" message and have the remote set their videoTrack to disabled.

Comment: OK. If I mute both the audio and video of remote user, is it equivalent to remote user not sending me any stream?

Comment: Well, technically speaking no. I believe he/she will still be sending a black image. (More info [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2058))